# Python - Compressed Image, Publisher/Subscriber

Tags: ros, python, subscribe, compressedimage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have implemented the code provided in:

http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/WritingImagePublisherSubscriber

however the published topic is empty. It does not contain any information. I tried to dump the topic information into a .txt file and it is empty. when I compare this with the topics published by the camera node, I get the right information (header, frame_id, data).

I printed the msg data structure before "self.image_pub.publish(msg)" (line 87) and the msg structure appears fine.

I have the compressed transport installed and working correctly as I can see the image from the camera node using image_view but not the /output/image (the topic published by the code from the link above). It is obvious I am missing something ... not sure what.

Any suggestion?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221900/python---compressed-image,-publisher/subscriber/) by [albspe](https://answers.ros.org/users/25240/albspe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2015-12-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved the problem: the issue was in using a mix of roslaunch and rosrun. Once I called the code from the link from the same roslaunch file with the camera then everything worked fine.

Not 100% sure why though as a rqt_view showed the right node-tree ...

---

Originally posted by [albspe](https://answers.ros.org/users/25240/albspe/) with karma: 36 on 2015-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1